# How to register for Alexa for Apps preview?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I would like to register for Alexa for Apps preview, as I want to add its functionality to a skill I have developed.
I tried to open the [register for preview](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps) link on the [About Alexa for Apps](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-apps/about-alexa-for-apps.html) page.
I expected the registration form to be loaded, but instead I found a generic "Alexa Skills Kit" presentation page.
There is only a [Learn More](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps) link under the Alexa for Apps section, but by clicking on it the page is just reloaded.
Is Alexa for Apps actually still in developer preview?

Comment: Yep, their links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Email address supplied on this page:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-apps/about-alexa-for-apps.html

i.e. alexaforapps-help@amazon.com

I've used that EMail address to register for Alexa Send to Phone successfully.  Although this was back in 2021!

Comment: Tried that, it's been 9 days and I'm yet to hear back :/